# Spark Dataset 2 level Depth aggregation

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

Which is the best solution 
to make a two level depth aggregation on dataset?

Let me explain better the problem.

Supposing we have users belong to one or more list and each one are provided by one or more partners.

We want to remove duplicate users in the same list merging its partners.

The dataset is about 1 billion users in thousand of list

*Raw Data*

```
user_id,list_id,partners
usr1 list1  [p1]                           
usr1 list1  [p1,p2]
```

*Elaborated Data*

```
usr1 list1  [p1,p2]
```

**Solution1**

1. convert dataset to `JavaPairRDD`  with userid and list as key
2. `reduceByKey` merge partners List (with no duplicate)
3. map tuple to new Record

**Solution2**

1. select dataset exploding partners
2. GroupBy user_id and list_id
3. collect_set on partners column

   ```java
   r.select(
               col("user_id"),
               col("list_id"),
               explode(col("partners"))
         .as("partners")
           )
    .groupBy("user_id","list_id")
    .agg(collect_set(col("partners")).as("partners")
   ```

These solutions works but I suspect I'm not using the best API instructions.
The application to reduce the entire dataset consider in key each user_id  I believe is very unbalanced in fact creates too many partitions one each users and I had bad performance.

I'm looking for a solution that at first aggregate the dataset by list and than collapse the same userid and finally it merges the partner list

can somebody  help me?

Thanks